# netbios-ssn Port 139 open on Linux machine

Tags: linux, port

all.

I'm desperately trying to pass a Security Metrics test, I've been trying for a few days, but I 'm always left with the same problem:

NetBIOS available on Linux
Service: netbios-ssn Port 139 open on Linux machine

I've been googling to no avail.

I've been trying to close port 139 and 445 with both iptables and fuser -k, but it still reports as open (to Security Metrics at least).
I've also tried to uninstall Samba and mess with the config file, there's just no way.

Any idea?!

Not sure what else to try...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo netstat -tanp`?

Comment: Is the server you are testing behind a NAT ?
Maybe the test is seeing another machine behind that NAT ?

Did you try to run nmap on the machine ? What is that saying ?

Comment: check `/etc/inetd.conf` for `netbios-ssn` entry (which usually runs `nmbd`)

Comment: @yarek I don't have that file... I have xinetd.conf but I don't see anything that could be related to it. :-)

Comment: @Tonny yes, nmap says port is closed using both localhost and the ip address...

Comment: @yarek I have /etc/rc.d/init.d , there I see:
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2994 Jun  7  2011 netconsole
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    5915 Jun  7  2011 netfs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1258 Jan 27  2010 netplugd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    8471 Jun  7  2011 network
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    5217 Jul 22  2011 nfs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    3701 Jul 22  2011 nfslock
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2145 Aug 30 01:42 no.smb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2517 Nov 28 16:21 nscd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    3353 Nov 18 14:21 ntpd
that could be related, maybe?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `iptables -nvL INPUT`

Answer (score 2):

Double check the IP/hostname they're scanning.  Does it match yours?  Do an external scan of your own, with nmap, to see if the port is open:

```
nmap -p 139 hostname (or IP)
```

If you still have difficulties, enlist the help of your web host (if you use one).  Most web hosts will help you secure your site per the PCI scan vendor's specifications, or at least point in the direction to get it fixed.

Comment: localhost says:
`rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
139/tcp closed netbios-ssn`

Comment: same thing using ip address. port is closed, looks like it reports open...

Comment: You're scanning locally?  Scan from a remote location to the public interface; this is the same interface your PCI scan vendor is scanning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to achieve PCI-DSS compliance and are stuck on this, then I think you need more help then a few answers here. There are some very good, free online training materials - I would recommend [the rute](http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz) as a good starting point. You should also read and apply the [SANS Linux checklist](http://www.sans.org/score/checklists/linuxchecklist.pdf).

> I've been trying for a few days

What have you tried?

> I've also tried to uninstall Samba

What have you tried?

> netbios-ssn Port 139 open on Linux machine

The first thing to check is if it really is netbios. As growse says netstat -natp will show you which program is listening on the port. If it is nmbd, then you need to shutdown the server *and make sure it never starts again* (i.e. uninstall everything you don't need).

The advice given by user171212 will probably work (it'll stop the service) but it's not the right way to control services. For sysV init files, it would be *more* correct to stop the service and remove the relevant links from the /etc/rc.d/rc*.d but the *correct* way to do it is via the [chkconfig](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-services-chkconfig.html) command. Indeed that "Security Metrics" recommends such an approach makes me think that any advice / service they provide should be treated with extreme prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while ago, my solution was simple, very simple.

```
sudo service smbd stop
```

The above command will close the service `smbd` as well both ports 139 and 445, since it is being used by `smbd`.
Do not try to close ports with `iptables`, it is a packet filtering only. To close ports you need to close the service using the port.

Answer (score -1):

from Security Metric's own page on the subject:

To Permanently disable (RedHat):
1. cd /etc/rc.d/init.d/
2. smb stop
3. mv smb no.smb
 
(ports 137 & 138 will also be closed)

Reference: https://www.securitymetrics.com/howtos/139.adp

Comment: This is not how to stop/disable the service - see answer elsewhere.

Comment: I agree from a Linux admin perspective that it's not a preferred method.  But the guy is asking about a solution for a problem with Security Metrics, and they offer a solution to their own scan findings.  It IS a way to stop/disable the service, it satisfies the scanner, so it is a relevant answer.  Knocking down my rep on it doesn't change that fact that it does, indeed, work.